# fgets() issues with for loop in C

Tags: c

Why am I getting the following output when fgets is outside for loop:

> Jim, Engineer
>
> Jim, Engineer
>
> Jim, Engineer
>
> Jim, Engineer

and the following output when fgets is inside for loop:

> Jim, Engineer
>
> Pam, Nurse
>
> Scar, Troublemaker
>
> John, Smith

```
int main()
{
    int i;
    char line[255];
    FILE *fpointer = fopen("employees.txt", "r");

    for (i=0; i < 4; i++){
        fgets(line, 255, fpointer);
        printf("%s", line);
    }
    fclose(fpointer);

    return 0
}
```

within fget(), "i" is not passed as an argument so how is it still iterating over each line in the .txt file?

Comment: `fpointer` gets updated inside `fgets`

Comment: I don't understand

Comment: Are you saying that `fgets(...); for(...) printf(...)` prints the same line 4 times?  Why is that surprising?

Comment: Each `fgets` reads a single line, placing it in `line`.  If you call it 4 times, printing `line` after each call, you will print those 4 lines.  If you call it once, outside of the loop, then the loop is just going to print the first line 4 times.

Comment: No Will, I am trying to understand how fgets() gets incremented when I haven't passed the incrementer "i" into it

Comment: Thanks Tom, how do I check your answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fgets` will read the file using `fpointer` (think of it as a cursor), and will increment it. So every time you use `fgets` you move forward in the file.

Answer (score 1):

While you already have a fine answer explaining the movement of the *file position indicator* with a file-stream each time a call to `fgets()` (or any other input function is made), one additional necessary point not to be overlooked is to *Always check the* **return** of the input function to ensure the call succeeded *before* using the information read.

In your case, when using the `for` loop, if there are less then 4 lines in the file, or if a stream-error occurs, you blindly pass the `line` to `printf` for output without ever knowing if it contains valid data. This is an invitation for *Undefined Behavior*. Always check the return.

When reading data, you generally want to control the input loop with the read function itself. In other cases, such as when requesting specific user input, you want to loop continually until the needed information is provided. In both cases you are checking and using the return of the input function to determine whether the loop continues.

To read all lines in the file, presuming that was your input, you would simply do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char line[255];
    FILE *fpointer = fopen("employees.txt", "r");

    while (fgets(line, 255, fpointer)) {    /* control read loop with fgets */
        line[strcspn (line, "\r\n")] = 0;   /* trim \n from end of line */
        puts (line);
    }
    fclose(fpointer);

    return 0;
}
```

If your intent is to read a specific number of lines, then simply include a counter, e.g. to read 4 lines:

```
int main()
{
    size_t n = 0;
    char line[255];
    FILE *fpointer = fopen("employees.txt", "r");

    /* control read loop with counter and fgets */
    while (n < 4 && fgets(line, 255, fpointer)) {
        line[strcspn (line, "\r\n")] = 0;   /* trim \n from end of line */
        puts (line);
        n++;
    }
    fclose(fpointer);

    return 0;
}
```

That way you have incorporated the return of `fgets()` and your line-count into the loop conditional.

(**note:** the use of `strcspn`, which returns the number of characters in the string NOT part of the exclude set `"\r\n"`, provides the length of the string excluding the line-ending allowing you to simply overwrite the first line-ending character with `'\0'` or its numeric equivalent `0`. It essentially does the following:)

```
        size_t len = strlen (line);
        if (len && len - 1 == '\n')
            line[--len] = 0;        /* trim \n from end of line */
```

Let me know if you have further questions.